# Connecting an Internal IDE hard-drive to a laptop

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My old desktop computer died yesterday, I want to take some of the information out from my internal hard drive to my laptop, I was checking around and I found this adapter (Wiretek USB2.0 to IDE / SATA Adapter):

http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/PID-MX13054(ME).aspx

Is this the best way to connect it? or it is possible to find something cheaper and/or better?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is whether it might be the hard drive that died.  As one of the main moving parts to a PC, hard drives are also one of the parts that are more prone to failure.

***If*** it turns out you have a good drive, then using an enclosure is certainly one option.  But there's no need to spend $50 for it.  You can get by for as little as $15:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010010092%201053807123%204093&bop=And&ActiveSearchResult=True&Order=PRICE